# Is there a quicker way to select the "selected" value of an HTML dropdown in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently using this garbage code to select the correct `selected="selected"` value for my HTML dropdown. There has got to be a better way... maybe with a switch statement or something else?

Any tips on how to make this more efficient?

```
if ($quantity == 0)
{
    echo '
    <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9+">9+</option>
    ';
}
else if ($quantity == 1)
{
    echo '
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9+">9+</option>
    ';
    }
else if ($quantity == 2)
{
    echo '
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9+">9+</option>
    ';
}
else if ($quantity == 3)
{
    echo '
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9+">9+</option>
    ';
}  etc....
```

Comment: Just use a loop to generate all those values.http://stackoverflow.com/a/20177824/1745672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo "<select>";
for($count = 0; $count < 10; $count++)
    echo "<option " . ($quantity == $count ? 'selected': '') . " value='$count'>$count</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: here's what your code outputs: `<option '')value="0" 'selected':="" ?="" 0="" (="=">0</option>`

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through them and print each one's HTML code, like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $value=$i;
    if($value==9) $value="9+";
    if($i==$quantity){
        echo '<option value="' . $value . '" selected="selected">' . $value . '</option>'
    }
    else{
        echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over it:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
    if($i == $quantity){
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    }else{
        $selected = '';
    }
    $i2 = ($i == 9) ? '9+' : $i;
    $select_options .= '<option value="'.$i2.'" '.$selected.'>'.$i2.'</option>';
}

echo $select_options;
```

Edit: looks like you can't set selected in the select its self, which is pretty stupid if you think about it. I've filed a complaint with the html5 standards people. its illogical to set the selected value of a select element in the individual options.

Comment: @kittycat3141 then you did something wrong. selected must be equal to the value of the option you want to be selected for example `selected="5"` would select the option with the value of `5`

Comment: Maybe it's my browser, but I checked and the "selected" attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: well i be damn. you are right. i guess you have no choice but to loop over them in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop is all you need :

```
$out='<option';
for($i=0;$i<10;i++){

if($quantity==$i)
$out.='selected="selected" ';

$out.=" value='$i'>$i</option";

echo $out;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually interpolate the 'selected' variable in to the loop

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
     $selected = $i==$quantity? 'selected="selected"':'';

        echo "<option value=\"$i\" $selected>$i</option>";

}
```