# Dynamic value count in dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a dropdown select menu as followed:

I have a table of products and each have a stock column. Let's say a product has a stock of 54. I want the dropdown to start at option 1 all the way to option 54.

Right now I have this:

```
<?php
## Conection part 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {   ## 1 While loop 

?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?= $row['ProductID'] ?>" /></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['ProductID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo utf8_encode($row['ProductName']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['SKU']; ?></td>
        <select>
          <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
<?php  
  }
$conn->close();
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is the stock column named `stock`? Also, do you want to do this in php or jquery? Php is done on the server before the page is loaded and jQuery is done on the client side after the page is loaded.

Comment: Column name is stock. Don't really mind if it's php or jquery. Whichever is easiest to make :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a PHP Dropdown menu from a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177788/create-a-php-dropdown-menu-from-a-for-loop)

Comment: Not completely. I want the max value of the dropdown to match the number of stock in the column.

Comment: They are both easy, but *easy* depends upon the coding that you are familiar with. Both are done with simple `for()` loops

Comment: Perhaps php then, as most of the code I use in this script is php. Only using jquery for a datepicker :).

Comment: well just change the `max` to your `$row['stock']`, ie. `for($i=1; $i<=$row['stock']; $i++){  echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>"; }`

Comment: @Sean: Perfect man! With all the php I've done so far, never really had any experience with this. Can you post it as an answer so I can check it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using a simple [`for()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop, where you change the `max` in `for($i=min;$i<=max;$i++)` to your `max`, ie. `$row['stock']`.

```
<select>
  <?php for($i=1;$i<=$row['stock'];$i++){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

also, if you want to account for when `$row['stock']` is `0`, you could show an `out of stock` message -

```
<?php if($row['stock'] > 0){ ?>
<select>
  <?php for($i=1;$i<=$row['stock'];$i++){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } else { ?>
out of stock
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use range to avoid a loop.

```
$stockValue=50;
echo "<select><option>".implode('</option><option>', range(1,$stockValue))."</option></select>";
```