# How to assign a php variable during HTML code?

Tags: php

Is it possible to assign a php variable durin html code, I've created my first php Programm and i wanted to make a dropdown bar like this:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to assign the variable "x", to the value, the user of the website has chosen.

Comment: are you looking for  <option>$x</option>    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177788/create-a-php-dropdown-menu-from-a-for-loop

Comment: Your select needs a name `<select name="something">`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<select>

    <?php

    $x = "value";

    foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {

        echo "<option value=\"" . $x . "\">" . $i . "</option>";
    }
    ?>

</select>
```